# How to detect if there are anything after a certain character by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm currently writing a google app script to scan a column of cells.

I'd like to get the cells which their string has nth after "=".

i.e. Cell A1: "abc=" 
A2: "abc" 
A3: "abc=we=" 
A4: "abc=def=ghi="

i wanna get cell A1, A3, A4.

How to do that? Thanks

Comment: What does `i.e. abc= / abc=we= / abc=def=ghi=` have to do with `string has nth after "="`

Comment: Check the last character in the all cells: `/\=$/`.

Comment: You could also use `slice(-1)== "="`, I think.

Comment: i think slice(-1) may work, but wt if the string is "abc= "?, it will take the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function findEndsInEqual() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var foundA=[];
  vA.forEach(function(e,i){
    if(e.toString().trim().slice(-1)== "=") {
      foundA.push("A" + Number(i+1));
    }
  });
  Logger.log(foundA);
}
```

Comment: i think slice(-1) may work, but wt if the string is "abc=  "?, will it take the space instead?

Comment: I added `trim()`; I also used a foreach instead of a loop in an effort to move away from my old school approach.

Comment: BTW I tried trimEnd() and evidently Google Apps Script doesn't support that.